# What can one do with laptop which won't turn on?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, battery, power

My laptop (HP probook 4510s) won't turn on. I would like to know what steps one should do in such cases to diagnose the problem and to know which part of laptop to replace.

## What I tried in my case (You can skip reading this section)

The last time the laptop is on I saw that it is not charging. So I thought that the problem could be with power adapter. I tried two different power adapters, different wall sockets the laptop still wasn't charging.

So I turned the laptop off (the last time) and then I wasn't able to turn it on anymore.

I disconnected the battery. I know that the laptop can be turned on without battery so I tried. It didn't work. So I suspect that the battery isn't problem.

I thought maybe the connector is worn-out and that there is some bad contact. However when I watched the diodes signalize something when inserting the powercord. (Orange and then blue light.)

I interpret this as: "The laptop knows that is is plugged in."

I have read that the acpi circuit can be in wrong state and that one can reset it (and discharge static electricity) by holding power button for 30seconds. It didn't work.

So I decided to replace motherboard. However is this conclusion correct? I started disassembling the laptop to see what motherboard I need.

The connector is connected to motherboard via short cable. (There is no intermediary board with this connector and electronic circuits which could be broken.)

I disconnectd keyboard and touchpad and suddenly the laptop started working. This wasn't the first time the problem has had problems with charging. This is the second time when I tried to solve it by turning off the laptop and then ended up disassembling the laptop which I can't power on. But it is the first time I realized what make the laptop work again.

## The questions (Continue reading here)

Disconnecting the touchpad and keyboard made it working again and it still works after reconecting them. What should I replace? Motherboard? Keyboard? touchpad? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some button or a lead is shorted on your keyboard or touch pad? Check whether you can reproduce the problem. Connect the keyboard back and reboot to see if the laptop refuses to boot again. 
If the problem can be reproduced I would try isolate if further, is it keyboard or motherboard? Try to clean the keyboard contacts, etc. Maybe buy a new keyboard (cheaper option than buying new motherboard) and check if the problem persists.

Comment: This is exactly what I would recommend.